# How can I use a loop to create lag variables?

Tags: loops, date, stata

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input int(date date2)
18257 16112
18206 16208
17996 16476
18197 17355
18170 17204
end
format %d date
format %d date2
```

I'm trying to create a loop in Stata that generates four variables (lags at 0 months, 3 months, 12 months, and 18 months).  I tried this (below) and I get an error: invalid syntax

```
foreach x inlist (0,3,12,18) & foreach y inlist (0,90,360,540){
    gen var`x' = (date > date2 + `y')
    
}
```

Here is a way for me to successfully create these variables without the loop. It would be much nicer if it could be simplified with a loop.

```
gen var0=(date>date2)
gen var3=(date>date2+90)
gen var12=(date>date2+360)
gen var18=(date>date2+540)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: you need just one loop over 4 possibilities, as 0 3 12 18 and 0 90 360 540 are paired.

```
foreach x in 0 3 12 18 { 
    gen var`x' = date > (date2 + 30 * `x') 
    
}
```

`foreach` requires either `in` or `of` following the macro name, so your code fails at that point. There is also no construct `foreach` ... `& foreach ....`: perhaps you are using syntax from elsewhere or just guessing there.

Comment: Thank you for the tips!  This is very concise.